# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib' despite passlib already being installed

Tags: python, passlib

I have a python module that tries to import `from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256`, however when running the module, I get the ModuleNotFoundError.

I have tried running the module in my base environment, a venv, in a poetry shell, and I've tried reinstalling passlib through poetry install, pip install, pip install --force-reinstall, and none of it gets the module to see passlib being installed. I'm at a complete loss as to why this library just won't work.

The full error message is:

> poetry run src/api-keychain/main.py --help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX/src/api-keychain/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from crypto import encrypt_key, decrypt_key
  File "XXX/src/api-keychain/crypto.py", line 5, in <module>
    from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib'
```

Answer (score 12):

Since you mentioned about you successful installed passlib, I guess you might not install it with the python interpreter you are using.

First Try:

```
pip install passlib
```

If not work, it could because you have both Python2 and 3 try:

```
pip3 install passlib
python3 -m pip install passlib
```

And if you have an IDE like Pycharm, you can use it to check what packages are with the interpreter you are using via go to the **Interpreter Settings**.

Comment: Just adding a note, the ````pip install passlib````  command pipeline needs to be ran in the project directory of the virtual environment, right?

Answer (score 1):

Installation with `pip` or `pip3` is not always fix the issue, sometimes you have multiple `venv` running on your machine.

I fixed the issue by deactivating the `venv`:

My issue is I create a `venv` via this command:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Because I have multiple interpreters, for some reason some packages are not recognized sometimes `sqlalcamey` package and sometimes the `passlib`, so I tried to activate the virtual environment as follows:

Activate the `venv`:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Now my Terminal has `(venv) (base)` prefix before any new command.

Then I deactivate the `venv`:

```
deactivate
```

Now my terminal is back to `(base)`, after that, I ran `pip install passlib` everything works fine now.

You need to be careful what is the issue, **missing package** issue, or **virtual environment** issue